# Need to Find Min & Max date specific status column value in SQL

Tags: sql

Below table Product:

```
+--------------+-----------+--------+-----------+
| Product_code | Prod Name | Status |   Date    |
+--------------+-----------+--------+-----------+
| A            | AA1       | New    | 12/3/2019 |
| A            | AA2       | Expiry | 7/20/2017 |
+--------------+-----------+--------+-----------+
```

expected output:

```
+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+
| Product_code | Min_date  | Min_status | Max_date  | Max_status | count_Prod |
+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+
| A            | 7/20/2017 | Expiry     | 12/3/2019 | New        |          2 |
+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

Tried with below query

```
SELECT Product_code,MIN(Date) as "Min_date", MAX(Date) as 
"Max_date",count(Prod_Name) as "count_Prod"
FROM Product where Product_code ='A'  
GROUP BY Product_code
ORDER BY Product_code;
```

Need a help to pull the specific status for date column.

Comment: What ordering does `Status` have? What type is it: text or some enumeration? How should one determine `Min_status` and `Max_status`?

Comment: Please tag the database you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below query. You can use Min and Max function for string column as well. It aggregates based on the alphabetical order.

```
SELECT Product_code,MIN(Date) as "Min_date", MIN(Status) as Min_Status,  MAX(Date) as 
"Max_date", MAX(Status) as Max_Status,count(Prod_Name) as "count_Prod"
FROM Product where Product_code ='A'  
GROUP BY Product_code
ORDER BY Product_code;
```